# Implementing a LinkedListNode that exposes an Add method

Tags: linked-list

I am a beginner and am studying Linked Lists. I found code that uses a Linked List Node that exposes an AppendToTail() method. However, the code doesn't share its implementation. It's my understanding that a Node class typically has only two members: object data; and Node next; and typically there are no methods within the Node class. Methods for adding a node to the head/tail are usually contained within the LinkedList class.

Can someone point me to an implementation that exposes a standard method like AppendToTail() from a Node object? So the same node will allow me to set its data field of course: LinkedListNode result = new LinkedListNode(); result.data = 5; And also allow: result.AppendToTail(anotherNode); where AppendToTail() appends anotherNode to the end of the list.

Comment: The Java collections class [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) has an add to tail method.  One option would be to just keep track of the head and tail.  If you can only keep track of the head, then you'd have to walk down the entire list to add to the tail.

Comment: Thanks Tim, but it's my understanding that the collection you pointed me to wouldn't expose an Add() method from a node object, it would expose Add() from a LinkedList object.